# Quick fix - should I handle sequence reset and resend request in code

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am using SocketInitiator in quickfixj to create FIX connection and send FIX messages to a third party. Session reset happens at midnight everyday. My query is if during a day if sequence goes out of synch (due to some network or hardware failure), I will start receiving sequence reset and resend requests (35=2, 35=4). Should I handle these 2 types of messages in the code and do something to reset the sequence or to start sending old messages. Or is it automatically handled in quick fix. Please provide some guidance on this.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Quick-Fix latest version, you need not handle these situations. Quick-Fix library automatically handles it. Place the parameter ResetOnLogon=N,in the Configuration file if you want the sequence number to be continued. If you want to start the sequence number from 1 then set it to ResetOnLogon=Y. Quick-Fix automatically handles if any session disconnect happens. Please see the Quick-Fix configuration details [here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html)